# plsql : New function inside an existing package compilation and syntax check

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, compilation, syntax-checking

How do I compile a new function created inside a package in plsql, to see syntactical error and so on

Answer (score 0):

You can't compile a single function - compile the whole package.

If your concern is about invalidating the whole package in case that function has errors, then

- create a standalone function (i.e. outside of the package)
- debug it
- once it is OK (doesn't have syntax errors, returns result as expected), include it into the package

Comment: ok, thanks, I've done that gives no syntax error, but I was not confident enough.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Littefoot's advise I'd say: use a proper GUI. Oracle has a free tool called sql developer. It has a great interface for editing database objects (packages/functions/procedures/triggers). It highlights errors and is very well documented (https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/sql-developer/). Note that is does not point out syntax errors - but once you're a bit used to working with pl/sql they become obvious very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, after compiling a procedure/function/package. If there is an error then the command will return with the message:

```
ORA-24344: success with compilation error
```

You can then use:

```sql
SHOW ERRORS
```

or

```sql
SELECT * FROM USER_ERRORS;
```

or, for example, for errors with packages in a specific schema:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   ALL_ERRORS
WHERE  owner = 'SCHEMA_NAME'
AND    type IN ( 'PACKAGE', 'PACKAGE BODY');
```

Which will list the errors (complete with line numbers and error messages) and you can then debug the procedure/function/package and recompile it.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/huRB6B4j)